# Replacing between chracters by unicode identifier

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to replace between two characters in a string based on their Unicode code point  ?? Could any help please ??Many Thanks.

For example,

```
 Replace (U0041 with U0066)
```

Comment: And what is a "code point" ? Post a proper question with one or more  examples.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I assume the OP means "Unicode code point" - but the rest of the question is indeed unclear. Perhaps the OP is considering characters which aren't in the BMP? More information definitely required.

Comment: @Henk, The code point i mean is the ASCII for characters. Thank you

Comment: @Qaesar: So what have you tried? And are you trying to replace each character with another single character?

Comment: @Jon, I'm trying to replace some characters  that I know their Unicode code point. I have updated the question . Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `replace("\u0041", "\u0066")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("ABC".Replace("\u0041", "\u0066"));
```

This produces the output `fBC`, because the unicode code point of `u0041` (which is `A`) has been replaced with the code point of `u0066` - an `f`.

Comment: Thank you dasblinkenlight, I just was worry that which code point I have to use . the (hexadecimal) or the (decimal). Know O got it . Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\u` escape code to write the characters:

```
str = str.Replace('\u0041', '\u0066');
```

Alternatively, convert the numbers into characters:

```
int char1 = 65;
int char2 = 102;
str = str.Replace((char)char1, (char)char2);
```